# Mongoose TypeError 'cannot read namespace' of undefined in collection.js in Mongoose module

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I run my application using NPM it runs without issue. When running it with my VSC debugger I receive the following error on two occasions in collection.js located in node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'namespace' of undefined
    at Object.get [as dbName] (/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:184:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:184:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/index.js:8:22)
```

Instance 1 picked up here:

```
Object.defineProperty(Collection.prototype, 'dbName', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function() {
    return this.s.namespace.db;
  }
});
```

Instance 2 picked up here:

```
Object.defineProperty(Collection.prototype, 'collectionName', {
  enumerable: true,
  get: function() {
    return this.s.namespace.collection;
  }
});
```

My connection configuration located in app.js looks like this (it works when running the application using NPM without any errors):

```
  const dbUser = process.env.xxxxx;
  const dbPass = process.env.xxxxx;
  const dbURL = process.env.xxxxx;
  const dbName = process.env.xxxxxx;

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.connect(`mongodb+srv://${dbUser}:${dbPass}@${dbURL}/${dbName}`, {useNewUrlParser: true , useUnifiedTopology: true} )
  .then(_ => console.log('MongoDB successfully connected!'))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The only Mongoose model in this application that loads Mongoose is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// UserSchema has been omitted for privacy
const UserSchema = new Schema({
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

There are no other instances where the Mongoose module is loaded. I've also checked the options I'm passing in the `mongoose.connect` method and it doesn't appear to be them either. Additionally I checked values stored in the `env` file and they also don't appear to be causing the issue.

Thanks, any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

update nodemon , mongoose

```
npm i -g nodemon
npm i mongoose
```

if you are getting warnings for package dependencies e.g:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
=> npm i fsevents
```

than install the optional dependencies too.

Comment: I just tried the above and unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Update your mongoose package too.

Comment: Yes, followed to the letter - does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Update mongoose v5.8.11. Today (01/31/2020) it has been released.

FYI -

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8528#issuecomment-578221253